# Why only chrome (and maybe safari) works good with transition (height,width)?

Tags: css, fade, css-transitions

I have a textarea, which stretches (makes height bigger) smoothly:

```
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
  height:20px;
  width:170px;
  transition-property: all 0.2s linear; /* PS: I don't want to write all prefixes in this question */
}
  textarea:focus {
  height:30px;
}
</style>
<div style="overflow:hidden;"><!--And some good styles-->
  <textarea style="resize:none;padding:10px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

So, in chrome `<div>` stretches smoothly (and `<textarea>` too, what I want), but in opera and firefox `<textarea>` stretches smoothly, but `<div>` doesn't.

I tried to add transition to `<div>`, but without result..

Is there a solution of this? (PS: I have some ideas to solve it with javascript: just add class to `<div>` onfocus, but can I solve it without js?)

Comment: a suggestion would be to use js, e.g. jquery... even if you get it to work in opera and firefox, what about IE, especially older versions?

Comment: `transition: all 0.2s linear;` is a better way to do it. Here you put properties and duration in the `transition-property` value.

Comment: @Chris : the question is about css3, don't start a troll.

Comment: @samsamX and Krylovech: well just mentioning, I don't mind as I am not an IE user either ;) however a good practice would be to make a site as cross-browser functional as possible, as IE users are (unfortunately) still majority... but it is your decision anyway :) great that it works now! :)

Comment: @Chris, it's good practice, yep. I have a lot practice, so, now I would like to make a good project with using modern, good technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did it: I just add class "active" to `<div>` on focus of textarea, and on blur: remove class "active" from `<div>`. All transformations doing by this class, like

```
div {
  height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
div textarea {
  height: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
div.active textarea {
  height:30px;
}
div.active {
  height:40px
}
```

It works very well.